# python write can take 2 arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I have a question to make an "output.txt". 
I would like to write both word and prob(l.19) results into 
an "output.txt" file.
When I write "model_file.write(word, prob)", the terminal scolds me with 
"TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" message.
I tried to add more arguments but it didn't work..
Could anybody help me with my question??

THIS IS A WORD COUNT.PY

```
total_count = 0 

train_file = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
for line in train_file:
    words =  line.strip().split(" ") 
    words.append("</s>")
    for word in words:t
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1 
    total_count = total_count + 1

model_file = open('output.txt',"w")
for word, count in sorted(counts.items(),reverse=True):
    prob = counts[word]*1.0/total_count
    print "%s --> %f" % (word, prob) 

model_file.write(word, prob)
model_file.close()
```

#

Answer (score 3):

Just simply replace

`model_file.write(word, prob)`

with

`model_file.write(word+' '+str(prob)+'\n')`

---

Be aware that the method `write()` was implemented to take **only one string argument**, so you have to convert `prob` into a string (by the method `str()`) and then combine it with `word` by the string operator `+`, so that you got only one string argument.

---

P.S.: though you didn't ask this, I have to say that if you are going to write each word and its probability, you should put `model_file.write(word+' '+str(prob)+'\n')` **into the `for` statement**. Otherwise, if you resist to call it outside of the `for` statement for some purpose, then you should assign `word` and `prob` outside of the `for` statement too. Or it would cause another error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `print` statement to do this:

```
print >>model_file, word, prob
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanna to created a kind on description about my df so I write this:

```
# Create an empty txt
f = open(os.path.join(pathlib.Path().absolute(),'folder','florder','name.txt'), "a")

# Create an kind of header
f.write('text'+'\n')
f.write('text'+'\n')
f.write("""
-------------------
""")
f.write('text:'+ '\n')
f.write("""
""")


for c in range(0, len(df.columns)):
        campo = df.columns[c]
        if df[df.columns[c]].dtype== 'object':
            text= 'Tex'
        outfile = open('name.txt','w')
        f.write('str:'+"'"+str(xxx)+"'"'\n')
        f.write('str:'+ str(str)+'\n')
        f.write('\n')
f.close()
```